# Switching theme to AppCompat draws actionbar MenuItem icons smaller

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-theme

I've inherited support for an app that is used with a particular manufacturer's Tablet/Device with mdpi screen resolution. The code was written using the Theme.DeviceDefault and the actionbar menu item's icons are stored in a drawable-mdpi folder.

In order to take advantage of the TabLayout api, I switched to Theme.AppCompat. The undesirable side effect of doing so is that now the ActionBar menuItem icons are drawn considerably smaller. I've experimented with re-sizing the icons/drawables without success. What digging I have done suggests that the actionbar menu-items have a fixed padding or blank touch area and the icon embedded in the MenuItem will not fill the menu_item parent button.

Is there anyway of forcing the icon to fill the MenuItem while using the AppCompat theme? Any suggestion as to how to restore the action bar icon size to that previously seen with the DeviceDefault theme would be welcomed.

Comment: "In order to take advantage of the TabLayout api, I switched to Theme.AppCompat" -- if you have not done so already, ask the manufacturer if that is acceptable. They may want you to continue using `Theme.DeviceDefault`, so this app matches other apps that are pre-installed on the device. If this device ships with Android 5.0+, and therefore `Theme.DeviceDefault` resembles `Theme.Material`, you could cross-port `TabLayout` to work with `Theme.DeviceDefault`, or see if [my cross-port](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport) works with `Theme.DeviceDefault`.

Comment: The device is not Android 5.0+, but that said, I will likely pursue the approach of porting TabLayout (or writing my own) per your suggestion. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will gladly mark it accepted.

Comment: Well, it does not really answer your question ("Is there anyway of forcing the icon to fill the MenuItem while using the AppCompat theme?"). I merely offered a possible workaround that would be fairly unique for your case. I would presume that there is some way via your custom `Theme.AppCompat`-based theme to control the padding/margins on the menu items, but I have never looked for it.